# How to set Responsive Filemanager to return absolute url in TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Im using Responsive Filemanager with TinyMCE 4

I need to absolute url for inserting image url or any files. But it return relative path.

I need to set image src like `<img src="http://domain.com/source/slide.jpg">` but it return `<img src="source/slide.jpg">`

I tried this , but it doesn't work

```
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the javascript initialization you are using, that you have these lines in it:

```
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false,
convert_urls: true,
```

The key is to `convert_urls: true`